# Function to escape different variable types in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I got sick of writing queries in my PHP as:

```
"WHERE '" . Database::escape($var) . "'";
```

The escape() function just calls mysql_real_escape_string() - but it's there so I can extend support to other databases later.

Having to single quote strings in the query was making my code more cluttered. So my idea was to create an other function in my database class to 'prepare' a variable for a query:

```
static public function prepare($var)
{

    if (is_object($var) || is_array($var) ) {
        return " '" . Database::escape(serialize($var)) . "' ";

    } else if (is_bool($var)) {
        return ' ' . (int)$var . ' ';

    } else if (is_int($var)) {
        return ' ' . $var . ' ';

    } else if (is_string($var) || is_float($var)) {
        return " '" . Database::escape($var) . "' ";

    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unsupported variable type [' . gettype($var) . ']');
    }
}
```

Now the benefit here is that, I don't need to worry about which variables I pass to a query. However it raises two questions:

1. Am I handling each variable type properly?
2. For what reason (if any) should I not do this?

Comment: why dont use PDO ? U program in php5 ?

Comment: http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: What about NULL values, how would you pass those? And special values, like NOW(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? What about other column names, like col1, which would become a string instead of the value in col1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a) pepared statements and b) a database abstraction layer (like PDO).

What you are trying to do on your own has been solved already, you should not roll your own implementation.

If you go down that road you'll notice that this:

```
"... WHERE '" . Database::escape($var) . "'"
```

is pointless and dangerous. A clear separation of SQL code and parameters requires you to be more explicit and gets you on the safe side against SQL injection the same time:

```
"--- WHERE SomeField = ?"  /* the parameter (?) will be filled elsewhere */
```

It's worth noting that true vendor-independence in the database field is somewhere between hard and impossible, depending on your needs and priorities. So trying to write portable SQL *could* turn out as an exercise in futility unless you are willing to sacrifice a lot. For MySQL it starts even with the LIMIT clause, which you will find impossible to port to, say, SQL Server.

Comment: pdo is not a database abstraction layer but (quote) "a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP". There's only one thing PDO abstracts and emulates if necessary: prepared statements.

Comment: It abstracts away the whole need for "mysql_" "mssql_", "whatever_" prefixes that you would need otherwise. It is not a ORM or anything (if you mean that).  I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer applies to PDO.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't be doing this. Here's why: [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO::prepare](http://il.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

As for your function itself, what happens if you have something stored in a string (say `"5"`) that you want to store as an int? It'll still quote it anyway.

Comment: The database has a predefined type for each column, so it won't matter to it whether it's quoted or not. However, special values like NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP should not be quoted.

Comment: Well then you are going to be running into trouble, because how do you pass those values in? Certainly not as a string, because that would be quoted...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use parameterised queries and it will Just Work. That is the right solution, and it's not terribly tricky.

In PHP, use PDO to do this, its API is much more sane than mysql_ or mysqli_ and moreover, it can throw exceptions on errors and do other nice things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE userid = '{Database::prepare($userid}'";
```

to alleviate the typing issues. Though my suggestion is that if you are accepting inputs from a form, why not setup Database::prepare() to run through the $_REQUEST or $_POST to clean them up, or spit out a copy?

This is how I do it:

```
$safe_post = InputCleaner::clean($_POST);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = {$safe_post['userid']}";
```